# properly opening compressed QGis files (.qgz) by double-click on bionic LTS causes a catch-22 regarding default application for Zip archives

Tags: default-programs, file-type, qgis

Regularly using **QGis** on bionic 18.04.4 LTS makes me appreciate the possibility
to **open** a compressed `.qgz` file **by double click**.

1. This **seems to not be the default** after installing QGis.
2. Obviously, one can set the *default application* for this file type to QGis.
3. Doing so, which associates all `Zip archive (application/zip)` files to QGis,
   causes *every zipped file* to be opened by QGis, which mostly is disappointing and not the desired behavior.
4. One can always *re-define the default* app for `.zip` files as Archive Manager, but this leads back to state 1.

How do I **define default applications based on the discernible filetype AND the extension?**

OR: **what am I missing here?**

Comment: update **SOLUTION:**
this was due to a lacking mime-type definition in QGis. 

it is fixed by doing this: 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35424/files